# MyClass.prototype.settings = {} gets overwritten by second instantiation

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know why if I pass an object of arguments to my constructor, the setting property values get overwritten by subsequent instantiations.

This doesn't happen when I pass arguments as separate vars to the constructor.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/KJ4CU/ and below

```
// First class
function Person(args) {
    for(s in args) {
       this.arguments[s] = args[s];   
    }
}

Person.prototype.arguments = {
    "gender" : null,
    "name" : null
};

Person.prototype.getGender = function() {
    return this.arguments.gender;
};

// Second class
function Animal(gender, name) {
    this.gender = gender;
    this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.getGender = function() {
    return this.gender; 
};

var p1 = new Person({ gender : "gal", name : "Jane"});
var p2 = new Person({ gender : "boy", name : "John"});
var a1 = new Animal("female", "Tina");
var a2 = new Animal("male", "Toto");

document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = p1.getGender(); // boy
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = p2.getGender(); // boy
document.getElementById("a1").innerHTML = a1.getGender(); // female
document.getElementById("a2").innerHTML = a2.getGender(); // male
```

Comment: The `prototype` property is a shared property. Why are you using it if you want each instance to have its own?

Comment: Instance specific code *always* goes in the constructor. If you want that every instance has their own `arguments` object, you have to create the object in the constructor.

Comment: I just want to know why prototype.settings.gender gets overwritten and prototype.gender does not.

Comment: Because you mutate prototype.settings and not re assign it as you do with prototype.gender. Even if the second class had a prototype.gender it would be shadowed. For more information check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the object `arguments` is a property of the prototype of your object:

```
Person.prototype.arguments = {
    "gender" : null,          
    "name" : null              
};
```

When you instanciate `p2 = new Person()`, the prototype is shared with `p2`, and the constructor is called:

```
function Person(args) {          // Constructor
    for(s in args) {             // Executed for each call to 'new Person()'
       this.arguments[s] = args[s];   
    }
}
```

`this.arguments` is resolved as `this.prototype.arguments`, which points to `Person.prototype.arguments`: it is shared, it is the same object.

Hence when you modify `p2.arguments.name`, you modify `p1.arguments.name`.

Instead of using the prototype, try adding an `arguments` properties to Person in the constructor.

```
function Person(args) {          // Constructor
    this.arguments = {           // Executed for each call to 'new Person()'
        gender: args.gender,     
        name: args.name
    };
}
```

This way, `this.argument` is a new object every time you create a new `Person`.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/572996/1370722):

> In class-based systems, the *methods* (not the properties/fields)
>   are added to the prototype. Whereas an object's fields are instance-specific and
>   therefore added to the object itself during construction.

For more information on javascript prototypes, see also [this article](http://pivotallabs.com/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword/).

Comment: Funny, the link provided in your answer is pretty good but the answer with 739 is wrong. Inheritance by setting prototype of Child to an instance of Parent and not re using Parent constructor function in Child by doing `Parent.apply(this,arguments);` is a beginners attempt at using prototype at best. Not ashamed to admit that I made the same mistakes when starting out but the amount of upvotes does reflect how many JS programmers understand how prototype works.

Answer (score -1):

Your Animal class is how you should do it, I would stick with passing one object as arguments as it makes it more readable. In the constructor you can choose what to do with missing arguments (set a default or throw an error).

Passing one argument object makes it easier if you inherit as well: `Parent.call(this,args);`

```
function Animal(args) {
    this.gender = args.gender||"boy";//defaults to boy
    //make name mandatory
    this.name = args.name||false;
    if(this.name===false)
      throw new Error("Can't create an Animal without passing a name");
}
Animal.prototype.getGender = function() {
    return this.gender; 
};
var p1 = new Animal({ gender : "gal", name : "Jane"});
var p2 = new Animal({ gender : "boy", name : "John"});
```

Comment: @downvoter http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." I don't think this answer applies to those criteria.